# How to get the URI for a song from the MediaLibrary?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Trying to code a Windows Phone silverlight app, and I'm trying to copy a "song" instance from the `MediaLibray.Songs` collection, to IsolatedStorage; I'm using the `MediaHelpers` / `MediaParsers` / `Mp3MediaStreamSource` classes as well, but I'm unable to create the relative URI properly for the selected song in the MediaLibrary:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("[Application Name];component/temptrack.mp3",UriKind.Relative);
```

What is the right format for creating a URI for a song within the `MediaLibrary.Songs` collection? Or is it just not possible to do this?

Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or is it just not possible to do this?

It's not. You can't get the Uri for a given Song object.

Comment: Thanks for the quick clarification Claus! Is there any way at all to make a copy of a given Song object, within IsolatedStorage?

Comment: Nope. The Song/MediaLibrary is completely seperate.

Comment: Sorry to keep beating a dead horse, but can I create a stream copy of the Song?
I'm basically trying to play the same track from the MediaLibrary, but play it without it showing the artist/trackname in the Universal Volume Control; I need to play the same track while hiding all song data; is this possible?